# postgresql erro: value too long for type character varying(256)

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have looked into other solutions before but could not find out the problem from explanations. I am trying to run a python script where the data is loaded from an oltp MySQL database (AWS RDS) to an olap database on AWS Redshift. I have defined my table in Redshift as below:

```
create_product = ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
    productCode varchar(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    productName varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    productLine varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    productScale varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    productVendor varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    productDescription text NOT NULL,
    buyPrice decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    MSRP decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
    )""")
```

I am using a python script to load the data from RDS to Redshift. My function body to load

```
    for query in dimension_etl_query:
        oltp_cur.execute(query[0])
        items = oltp_cur.fetchall()
        try:
            olap_cur.executemany(query[1], items)
            olap_cnx.commit()
            logger.info("Inserted data with: %s", query[1])
        except sqlconnector.Error as err:
            logger.error('Error %s Couldnt run query %s', err, query[1])
```

The script run throws the error

**olap_cur.executemany(query[1], items)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(256)**
I have checked in my SQL database for each of the columns length and only productDescription has length greater than 265 characters. However I am using text datatype in postgres for that column. Would appreciate any tips on how to find the rootcause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-text-and-bpchar-types

> TEXT and BPCHAR types

> You can create an Amazon Redshift table with a TEXT column, but it is converted to a VARCHAR(256) column that accepts variable-length values with a maximum of 256 characters.

> You can create an Amazon Redshift column with a BPCHAR (blank-padded character) type, which Amazon Redshift converts to a fixed-length CHAR(256) column.

Looks like you might need `VARCHAR`, I think. From same link:

> VARCHAR or CHARACTER VARYING
> ...

> If used in an expression, the size of the output is determined using the input expression (up to 65535).

You will have to experiment to see if that works.

Comment: You are right, I've changed the TEXT into a VARCHAR(500). I think this is a deviation in Redshift from Postgresql.

Comment: It is, in Postgres `text` is a `varchar` of  unlimited length.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to keep everything under 256 chars even if it is a `text`

Comment: From what I understand, text is for unlimited length.

Comment: Im just trying to keep it simple for him :)